# Sampling points logarithmically on the x axis

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, sampling

How may I sample points logarithmically on the $x$ axis in the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ ? Basically I have a sharply peaked function nearing the interval border at $x_0$ such that a linear sampling does not give me the correct behaviour of the function. Of course, I may also do a linear sampling on the reduced interval $[x_0, x_r]$, where $x_r \simeq x_0$ which corrects for that but I'd like to try with a logarithmic sampling and plot accurately for the whole $x$ interval.

Before, the linear sampling was $x = x_0 + (x_1-x_0)/\text{incs}*i$, where $\text{incs}=10000$ say and then $i\in \left\{0,...,10000 \right\}$.

How to sample logarithmically between $x_0$ and $x_1$?

Comment: You can sample at the points $x_0+r\frac{x_1-x_0}{2^k}$ for some $1\geq r>0$ and $k=0,1,2,...$. The $2$ can be other numbers, but in a regular computer is probably convenient to use $2$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I see. So here, if $r=1$, then $k=0$ corresponds to $x=x_1$ while $k=10000$ corresponds to $x=x_0$?

Comment: For $k=10000$ is a point close to $x_0$, but not really $x_0$ (depending on the precision of your representation of the numbers in the computer). You can sample, $x_0$ itself in addition to the points above.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Is perhaps this sampling in $x$ converging to $x_0$ too quickly as $k$ increases (in my case after like twenty values of k, to the precision I am working at, already I was hitting $x=x_0$ so sampling towards the other side of the interval, towards $x_1$, is not optimal)? Maybe it's better to sample linearly for part of the x range then logarithmically for the part where the function is peaked?